# php regex optionally match a whole word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

im using php and i need to scrape some information from some curl responses to a site. i am simulating both an ajax request by a browser and a normal (entire) page request by a browser, however the ajax response is slightly different to the entire page request in this section of the html.

the ajax response is:
`<div id="accountProfile"><h2>THIS IS THE BIT I WANT</h2><dl id="accountProfileData">`

however the normal response is:
`<div id="accountProfile"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><h2>THIS IS THE BIT I WANT</h2><dl id="accountProfileData">`

ie the ajax response is missing the tag: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`. i need to get the bits in between the `h2` tags. obviously i can't just scrape the page for `<h2>THIS IS THE BIT I WANT</h2><dl id="accountProfileData">` since these tags may occur in other places and not contain the information i want.

i can match either one of the patterns individually, however i would like to do both in a single regex. here is my solution for matching the ajax response:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/\<div id="accountProfile"\>\<h2\>(.+?)\<\/h2\>\<dl id="accountProfileData"\>/';
preg_match($pattern, $haystack, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

can someone show me how i should alter the pattern to optionally match the `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` tag aswell? if it helps to simplify the haystack for the purposes of brevity that's fine.

Comment: The normal response is broken - a `html` element has no place inside the document. I'm not entirely sure what your question is? Have you considered using a DOM parser to parse the HTML? See [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/3577662#3577662)

Comment: broken it may be, but it its there all the same. i didnt write the site i am scraping. ok i updated the requirements a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but you can try this:

```
    $pattern = '/\<div id="accountProfile"\>(\<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"\>){0,1}\<h2\>(.+?)\<\/h2\>\<dl id="accountProfileData"\>/';
```

Comment: that works - as long as you escape everything in `xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` :) also you can simplify `{0,1}` to `?`

Comment: i wonder if its possible to write the pattern without brackets around the `html xmlns=...` tag? its no big deal, but php's preg_match  creates a new array element for anything matching a pattern in brackets. of course i can just use the final `$matches` array element, but im curious if its possible to avoid matching this unwanted `html xmlns=...` tag pattern.

Comment: @mulllhausen: You can use a non-capturing group by adding `?:` to the start of it, so: `(?:\<html ...)`